# Changing the font of a Large Titled Navigation Bar in Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar, preferslargetitles

How do I change the font of a Large Titled Navigation Bar in Swift?

I was unable to find a thread which covered implementing custom fonts for a navigation bar with a large title.

I am trying to use the font titled: "ヒラギノ角ゴシック W8.ttc". This appears to be pre-installed on my Mac. The name in the Font Book is: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic StdN".

This is what I have tried:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "ヒラギノ角ゴシック-W8", size: 20)!]
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "ヒラギノ角ゴシックW8", size: 20)!]
```

and

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Hiragino Kaku Gothic StdN", size: 20)!]
```

[image: Font]
The "W8" is the Bold version of this font.

Is the problem that the font file name is in a different language or is it something else?

Comment: Why does your iOS device care about which font family is loaded on your desktop computer?

Comment: You need to add the font files to your iOS project. I would suggest you try with existing different fonts available on iOS to experiment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image: Please check the images]
[image: how to add font in <code>info.plist</code>]

Fist make sure that your font is .ttf or .otf format

1) Import your font into the project
2) Add new key "Fonts provided by application" on application's `info.plist` file and add your font names Now you can use custom fonts with interface builder or programatically

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes =
    [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
     NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "your font name", size: 30) ??
                                 UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
```

Comment: Read the question.

Comment: first try my solution and add font into your xcode project

Answer (score 0):

Latest swift version:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes =
        [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: backIconColor,
         NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "your font name", size: 30) ??
                                     UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 30)]
```